# Use of XLSX and addDataFrame() to get proper header names

Tags: r, list, dataframe, xlsx

### List of data frames exported to Excel has DF name prepended

I am splitting a dataframe by city and the resulting *list of dataframes* export to their own Excel sheets, but the header of each dataframe is undesirably coming out as `Atlanta.type` and `Atlanta.kpi` instead of `type` and `kpi`.  I'd like to understand why this is happening and how I can fix it to meet my need.  My desired output should look like this (but it doesn't):

[image: Good header AND Good data!!!]

### Detailed Example

#### Setup

Here's a basic dataframe similar to the one in real life, and I'll split it by location into a list:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_Main <- expand_grid(location = c("New York", "Boston", "Atlanta"),
                  type = c("A"), 
                  kpi = c(1.5,3))

> df_Main
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  location type    kpi
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1 New York A       1.5
2 New York A       3  
3 Boston   A       1.5
4 Boston   A       3  
5 Atlanta  A       1.5
6 Atlanta  A       3
```

Now split it into a list of dataframes, one for each sheet I'll create:

```
lst_Main <- split(df_Main, f = df_Main$location)

> lst_Main
$Atlanta
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  location type    kpi
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1 Atlanta  A       1.5
2 Atlanta  A       3  

$Boston
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  location type    kpi
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1 Boston   A       1.5
2 Boston   A       3  

$`New York`
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  location type    kpi
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1 New York A       1.5
2 New York A       3
```

#### Trial 1

I put the list into a workbook using `library(xlsx)`, and while this does *work*, the column names in the resulting Excel file show the `Atlanta.type` and `Atlanta.kpi` column names:

```
library(xlsx)

wb = createWorkbook()

for (df in names(lst_Main)) {
  sheet = createSheet(wb, df)
  addDataFrame(lst_Main[df], sheet = sheet, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
}

saveWorkbook(wb, file = "./Excel Output/test.xlsx")
```

[image: Bad header name -- do not want the prepended city!]

#### Trial 2

I thought that perhaps it was because I didn't double-bracket the list, so I alternatively tried:

```
for (df in names(lst_Main)) {
  sheet = createSheet(wb, df)
  addDataFrame(lst_Main[[df]], sheet = sheet, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

This fixed the headers in the way I wanted them, the data isn't useful:

[image: Good header, but bad data format!]

#### Trial 3

As a last resort, I tried just adding a single straight dataframe to a workbook, and this turned out to export the good headers with the bad data, so perhaps my use of lists isn't the problem (?):

```
wb = createWorkbook()
sheet = createSheet(wb, "df_Main")
addDataFrame(df_Main, sheet = sheet, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

[image: Just add a simple dataframe -- but still wrong!]

### What I'm looking for

Based on Trial 3, I don't believe my use of lists is the problem (but maybe?). Primarily, I just want to know what is causing me to get the wrong output, is it my syntax or is my use of `library(xlsx)` just problematic (I know it uses java somehow). If the `library(xlsx)` package is the problem, what is a more reliable way to achieve these ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider wrapping with `unname`

```
for (df in names(lst_Main)) {
   sheet = createSheet(wb, df)
   addDataFrame(unname(lst_Main[df]), sheet = sheet, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
 }
```

-output

[image]

---

This also works with single file, if it is wrapped in a `list`

```
wb = createWorkbook()
sheet = createSheet(wb, "df_Main")
addDataFrame(list(df_Main), sheet = sheet, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

-output

[image]

---

The main reason OP's single data/multiple datasets are not working is because they are not `data.frame`, but `tibble`.  Consider changing it to `data.frame` and it will work

```
df_Main <- as.data.frame(df_Main)
wb = createWorkbook()
sheet = createSheet(wb, "df_Main")
addDataFrame(df_Main, sheet = sheet, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

-output

[image]

---

As part of negative check,  reconvert back to `tibble` and do this again

```
df_Main <- as_tibble(df_Main)
wb = createWorkbook()
sheet = createSheet(wb, "df_Main")
addDataFrame(df_Main, sheet = sheet, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

-output
[image]

---

The function itself says `addDataFrame` and the expected input 'x' according to `?addDataFrame` is

> x - a data.frame.

Comment: Just wrap it in a `list(df_Main)` and it should work

Comment: This is very helpful -- it answers the cases I cited in my OP.  It just feels off, however, that I have to wrap a dataframe in a list when I use `addDataFrame(x)` which uses a data.frame in `x`.  I'm inclined to just give a day or two to see if a better answer appears before I accept this one, but I am very grateful for this.  Thank you.

Comment: Nope.  That's it.  I'm new to R and I have read that there is a difference between a data.frame and a tibble (though they are close and often the same -- but not always), and that seems to be it.  I've been working exclusively with tibbles, and this is the first time it has mattered in what I'm doing.  Thank you for the detailed explanation.  I feel this fully explains my problems now.

Comment: @wackojacko1997 I was also perplexed by the behavior until I tried the example in the documentation.  I didn't check your data type earlier and then it was obvious. you may also use writexl or openxlsx package as those ha